# Horizontal pair of text input areas - top of one is lower than the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The text input area on the left side lines up at the bottom with the text area on the right.

I want them to line up together at the top. (The word "why" would be vertically placed in the same position as the words "is this.") How can I achieve this with CSS, or without a complex solution such as reading the element's new height while the user types and actively changing the boxes heights to match via JS/JQ, etc.?

---

http://64.179.188.97/memory3/login.php

User: testuser

Password: 1234

[image: High box]

Comment: Set them to equal heights.  Pretty straight forward, no?

Comment: @technophobia No, because the height changes based on the amount of data typed into it; it's live-update.

Comment: @Nemo-Omen the you have a problem with the calculation ^^

Comment: What about` Display:Table;`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of the relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want them to be different heights, but aligned at the top, you just need to give your element a `vertical-align: top;`.

**Result**

[image]